# As data for PySimplegui exit screen?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

This `def` is my script that scans a website for active links. In this case, I wanted to know how to get this data and put it on the `Pysimplegui` OUTPUT screen.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

sg.theme( 'Reddit' )


def prog() :
    r = requests.get( 'http://www.google.com' )
    html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup( html , 'lxml' )

    links = soup.find_all( 'a' , attrs={'href' : re.compile( '^http://)' )} )
    for link in links :
        href = link['href']
        return href


        layout = [
[sg.Output( size=(30 , 20) , key='For_EXIT' )] ,
[sg.Button( 'Read' ) , sg.Exit( )]

]

window = sg.Window( 'SCRIPT' ).layout( layout )

Button , values , event = window.read( )

enter = prog( ) and enter in values['For_EXIT']

print(f'enter: ['-IN-']')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

sg.theme( 'Reddit' )


def prog() :
    r = requests.get( 'http://www.google.com' )
    html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup( html , 'lxml' )

    links = soup.find_all( 'a' , attrs={'href' : re.compile('^http://')} )
    href = []
    for link in links :
        href.append(link['href'])
    return href


layout = [
[sg.Output( size=(38, 20) , key='For_EXIT' )] ,
[sg.Button('Read',key='Read') , sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('SCRIPT',layout=layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Read' :
        return_value = prog()
        window['For_EXIT'].update(value=return_value)
    if event == 'Exit' or event == None:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an Output element is so that you can "print" and have the output go there. You don't need to call `update` on these elements.  Calling print will put whatever you print there.

You want to be extremely careful with any operation that is lengthy.  These should be run as threads.

The result is that if you want to display the result of your call to `prog()`, then add this line:

```py
print(prog())
```